# c++14 - Are DBL_Max and DBL_Min subject to round off errors?

Tags: floating-point, double, c++14, precision, floating-accuracy

Floating point values can have round off errors. For example,

```
double x = 1.0;
// x might be something like 1.00000000000000001
```

Are constants like DBL_Max and DBL_Min always guaranteed to have the same value they're intended to have (for whatever system they're being used on)? Is it possible for them to be affected by round off errors? For example, in the code below:

```
double x = DBL_Max;
assert (x == DBL_Max); // is this assertion guaranteed to always be true?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C and C++ standards are not explicit about this. The C standard allows errors during conversions from floating-point constants (literals) in source code to internal format (as in C 2011 [N1570] 6.4.4.2 5) and does not explicitly disallow this for the constant expressions that `DBL_MAX` and `DBL_MIN` expand to. However, no sane C or C++ implementation will have inaccurate values of `DBL_MAX` or `DBL_MIN`.

The C++ standard does seem to say that floating-point literals must result in the exact value if they are representable. (C++ 2017 [draft n4659] 5.13.4 1 and similar text in the 2010 version: “If the scaled value is in the range of representable values for its type, the result is the scaled value if representable, else the larger or smaller representable value nearest the scaled value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.”) However, `DBL_MAX` and `DBL_MIN` are specified to be constant expressions, not literals. I do not find a statement in the normative part of the C++ standard about the accuracy of floating-point expressions, but a Note in 5.19 4 says: “Although in some contexts constant expressions must be evaluated during program translation, others may be evaluated during program execution. Since this International Standard imposes no restrictions on the accuracy of floating-point operations, it is unspecified whether the evaluation of a floating-point expression during translation yields the same result as the evaluation of the same expression (or the same operations on the same values) during program execution.”

So, technically, the standard does not require that `x == DBL_MAX` is true after `double x = DBL_MAX;`, but, in practice, it should always be true.

As noted above, in C++, the `1.0` in `double x = 1.0;` must be translated exactly, so `x` will be initialized to one with no rounding error. The C standard does not specify this, but no sane C implementation will have a rounding error in `double x = 1.0;`. Rounding errors arise from difficulties or impossibilities in computation, not from random artifacts.

Comment: Building on your last point, does that mean if x = 1.0, assert(x==1.0) is always true? I think I saw some other questions on SO where there is a round-off error if a variable is set to a literal.

Comment: @user18119: I typed that last paragraph before examining C++ 5.13.4 1, which seems to say that literals that can be represented exactly are translated exactly. So `1.0` should always yield exactly 1. (1 is always representable by the definition of floating-point, which is some number of digits in some base multiplied by the base to some power, so 1 is always representable as 1 times the base to the power of zero. Unless you want to consider a bizarre floating-point format where the exponent zero is out of bounds.)

Comment: @user18119: Also, the reason the C standard allows literals to be translated with rounding error even if they can be exactly represented is that writing good software to do the arithmetic needed to translate literals with many digits and exponents that are large in magnitude was difficult. It could always be done with the methods taught in elementary school, but that could sometimes require writing software to do arithmetic with hundreds of digits, and it was desired to allow C on small machines. Papers have since been published with good algorithms, so it is easier to do the job nowadays.…

Comment: … but that difficulty only applied to numbers with many digits and large exponents. Translating `1.0` and other simple numbers was always easy and should be done correctly by any C implementation even if the standard technically allows inaccuracies.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. It's odd the C standard hasn't been updated to be like C++ on this, but I assume it's due to back compatibility.